# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (imported class in javascript)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a class that I have in another js file, but can't figure out why I'm getting unexpected identifier error.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="graph" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<script src="./MyGraph.js"></script> 
<script>
window.onload = function() {

    MyGraph g = new MyGraph('graph');
    g.drawLine();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the MyGraph.js file:

```
class MyGraph {

    constructor(containerId) {

        this.canvas = document.getElementById(containerId);
        this.canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

    drawLine() {

        this.canvasContext.moveTo(25,25);
        this.canvasContext.lineTo(125,125);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: That's not *importing* the class. "Import" (now) has a specific meaning in JavaScript related to [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: `MyGraph g = new MyGraph('graph');` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+Uncaught+SyntaxError%3A+Unexpected+identifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `this.canvas.getContext('2d')`, because otherwise `canvas` is undefined. And you might want to add `stroke()` to your draw function (I'm guessing that's what you want).

```
class MyGraph {
  constructor(containerId) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(containerId);
    this.canvasContext = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  }
  drawLine() {
    this.canvasContext.moveTo(25,25);
    this.canvasContext.lineTo(125,125);
    this.canvasContext.stroke();
  }
}
```

And you have to use `const`, `let` or `var` to define variables:

```
window.onload = function() {
    let g = new MyGraph('graph');
    g.drawLine();
}
```

Comment: While true, that's not the problem that the OP asked about. It's the **next** problem they'll have, though. :-)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is loosely typed, you don't declare the type of variables. You use `let` or `const` (or `var` if you want to be old-fashioned);

```
    let g = new MyGraph('graph');
//  ^^^---- let, not MyGraph
```

It's not the error you asked about, but the *next* error you'll get (as [pointed out by Kresimir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53656327/157247)) is that you're missing `this` on this line in `MyGraph.js`:

```
this.canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
//                   ^-- Missing `this` here
```

JavaScript is not like Java or C# where the `this.` is optional.